# How to disable the model property validation of not-nullable properties?

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project. This works fine for most cases, so:

- Request body JSON syntax validation is done by ASP.NET Core.
- Request object property validation is done by FluentValidation.

But there is one specific case that is problematic:

- If the request type contains a not-nullable property (e.g. `string` instead of `string?`) and the request object contains a null value for it, validation is done by ASP.NET Core (but should be done by FluentValidation).

My current workaround is to annotate all that not-nullable properties with `[ValidateNever]` so that ASP.NET Core ignores them, but this is not nice.

Is there a way to disable ASP.NET Core model property validation of not-nullable properties?

Note: I can't disable ASP.NET Core validation completely because then it won't even return validation error results for JSON syntax errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to set as below :

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

The problem has been explained in this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.suppressimplicitrequiredattributefornonnullablereferencetypes?view=aspnetcore-6.0